# Storing a File object into a Serializable Object via TCP

Tags: java, file, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Hello does anyone know how to put a File object to a serializable object that can be passed through TCP connections? I currently have a Message object that can pass an Image and a String, now i want it to also pass files how can i do this with this skeleton.

I am using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. thank you very much.

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private transient Image image;
public String text;

public Message() {

}

//getters and setters...

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) {
    s.defaultReadObject();

    if (s.readBoolean()) {
        image = new Image(s);
    } else {
        image = null;
    }

}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s)  {
    s.defaultWriteObject();

    s.writeBoolean(image != null);
    if (image != null)
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), 
        "jpg", s);
}
```

Comment: Rather than having an actual Image Object  Use [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to convert that image to an byte array which is serializable

Comment: I see, so this byte array could I store it in this Message object that is serializable?

Comment: Yes. All primitive datatype and arrays are serializable by default